# vfork() atexit assertion failed

Tags: c, process, fork, atexit

I am trying to understand the following piece of code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int main()
{
pid_t pid ;
unsigned int i=0;
pid=vfork();
switch(pid)
{
    case -1: // some sort of error
        puts("fork error");
        break;
    case 0: // the child process 
        while(i<100)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            i++;
        }
        break;
    default: //parent
        while(i<1000)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            i++;
        }
        break;
}
//  _exit(0);
}
```

And please don't tell me that vfork() is bad and these kind of things .I know it is , but what is happening exactly in this code that is causing this kind of error .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you are trying to do or understand, but here is a slightly edited quote from [the manual](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/vfork.2.html):

> The vfork() function has the same effect as fork(2), except that the
>   **behavior is undefined** if the process created by vfork() either
>
> 1. modifies any data other than a variable of type pid_t used to store    the return value from vfork()
> 2. returns from the function in which vfork() was called
> 3. calls any other function before successfully calling _exit(2) or one of the exec(3) family of functions

You are doing both 1: `i++` and 3 `printf("%d\n", i)`. Whatever you expect, it won't work.

As a side note, `vfork` isn't bad. Just tricky, dangerous, almost useless and removed from SUSv4.

Comment: He's also doing (3) by commenting out the call to `_exit` -- when main returns it calls `exit` not `_exit` -- and that's probably where his problem with atexit comes from

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDodd , that was the catch , I tried commenting the whole code and stuff and found out that exit is be blamed . It is removing up the stack frame for the call to the parent

Comment: But , why is the code going on till "999" and then seg faulting ? If the activation record is removed , and so is the variable "i" .How , is it getting incremented and the code faulting , only when the main function from the parent is trying to return .I don't need any references from the man page etc. Please explain this from the operating systems point of view , Like the reason it crashes after main in parent is returning is because the parent is trying to return and pop the stack, but , the stack frame was already popped by the child while returning .That's why it segfaults .

Comment: Can anybody tell me how to debug it with gdb or something , to see what's actually happening behind the screen ?